# How to create requirejs bundles "manually"?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, bundle

I have this in my require js config:

```
require.config({
    bundles:{
        "testbundle":["foo","bar"]
    }
});
```

Now when I require foo or bar, it will try to load `js/testbundle.js`.

What should the contents of that file be, if 
`foo.js` is:

```
define([],function(){
    return {foo:"foo"}
});
```

and `bar.js` is:

```
define([],function(){
    return {bar:"bar"}
});
```

What if `bar.js` has some dependency on something that's not a part of the bundle, eg:

`bar.js`:

```
define(["baz"],function(Baz){
    return {bar:"bar"}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, just need to name my define calls

This would be valid for testbundle.js

And again getting nags from poorly formatted code, so let's double down on it

````
```
define("foo",["bar"],function(Bar){
    return {foo:"foo"}
});
define("bar",["baz"],function(Baz){
    return {baz:"baz"}
});
```
````